# Scraping a website, Google Sheets IMPORTXML function, get specific lines in columns

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets

I need to scrape the "Call date" and "Distribution dates" cells in the following link, and import the data into google sheets.

https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=acp-a&sopt=symbol

However, when I do it I get all the information in the specific cell. I am trying to just get the first line in the cell, but I have not been able to figure out how to do it. I have tried this:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol="&B2&"&sopt=symbol","//tr[@bgcolor='FFEFB5']/../tr[2]/td[6]")

For example when I use this I get the distribution dates in the sixth column but do not know how to to cut off the lines below that and just get the information on the first line. Same goes for the other columns.

Comment: This is how you can use alternatively `=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol="&B2&"&sopt=symbol","//tr[./th[.='Distribution Dates']]/following::tr/td[6]/font"),1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text()` and a predicate in square brackets to specify which text node you wish to select.

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=acp-a&sopt=symbol","//tr[@bgcolor='FFEFB5']/../tr[2]/td[6]/font/text()[1]")`

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what is searched for. Is it possible to make it even more specific?

Comment: You could use XPath string functions to perhaps select specific substrings, such as `=IMPORTXML("https://www.quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=acp-a&sopt=symbol","substring-before(//tr[@bgcolor='FFEFB5']/../tr[2]/td[6]/font/text()[1], ',')")`, but it depends on what you want to select.

Comment: Thank you, can this be applied to taking out the CUSIP number on the link?

Comment: Yes. For that you would do `substring-before(substring-after(<an XPath>, 'CUSIP: '), ' ')`